# Cannot fetch data from the website as the URL doesn't change when it grabs the data so data table is empty

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have just started webscraping using python. I have used two libraries for scraping: requests and beautiful soup. I open the given URL and on that page I pass the dates interval from which I want the data. The URL doesn't change when I press submit but the data is there on the page. Then I get the access to that page.
This is how I get access to the website:

```
r = requests.get("https://....... ")
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
```

If I want to get the data, I use the following code to fetch data from the website where data is stored:

```
all = soup.find_all("table", {"class":"table table-responsive table-data"})
```

My all variable is an empty list whereas on the website I can see that the data is there.

I know why this problem is happening. When I open the URL, the website asks me to submit some parameters i.e. dates in my case and then when I press submit, I get the data but the URL doesn't change.

Is there any way I can submit parameters too using requests or beautiful soup?
Or any other package to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its parameters you can use doing requests. If its hardcore authentication better to do it with selenium.

Section Passing Parameters in URL should clear this up - 
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

**GET**

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
```

**POST**

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

Comment: This is really helpful but now I am facing another problem. I am passing 4 parameters but the last 2 parameters are dynamic. So for the automation process it fails every time. Is there any way I can overcome this? @Vivek

Comment: shoudn't be a problem... define dynamic...any code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced, but in my opinion there would be an ajax call in that page, You have to see on which URL its sending call, then response of that Ajax populates data which you need.

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful soup doesn't support POST requests, so you need to use another library for that.

I recommend [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

Then you can do something like this (this is just an example you have to adapt it to your needs):

```
import requests
import BeautifulSoup

formData = {'date_1':'1111111', 'date_2': '111111'}
request = requests.post('https://...', data = formData)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content)
all = soup.find_all("table", {"class":"table table-responsive table-data"})
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I did  this thing exactly. Its working but now I am facing a problem to automate this process as last 2 parameters I am passing are dynamic. @Henrique